# ts Property Push Doesn't Exist on the type '{}' in Angular code VS

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular7

I created an array

```
    messages: string[] =[];
```

After that I try to `push` a `string` value

```
    add(message: string){
       this.messages.push(message);
    }
```

in visual studio I have the error:

```
 [ts] Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `messages: string[] = new Array<string>();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I used in my project its works

```
public roles = new Array<any>();
```

And push your Enum Object into Array

```
for (let item in Role)

{
      if (item)
          {
                let temp=item;
                this.roles.push(temp);
               }
}
```

Need to check do `console.log(this.roles);`